# Neo4j import tool - OutOfMemory error: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, csv, import, neo4j, garbage-collection

I am using the neo4j-import tool (Windows) to import ~1 million nodes with ~20 million relationships, all of which should be unique. The process proceeds smoothly until it gets to the "Relationship Count" task, where it loads all the way up to 20M (seemingly all of the relationships) but then it hangs for awhile (30 min-1 hour), eventually returning "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded".

I have loaded large graph databases successfully before (39M nodes, 21M relationships) so I'm not sure what the issue is. Is it because the graph database is more densely connected compared to the previous database that I loaded?

Or, could there be a memory leak? In my task manager, the Java Platform SE Binary process requires an increasingly large amount memory (up to 12-13GB out of 16GB of RAM) as the import loads, especially towards the end. This seems suspiciously large, especially since the 39M node/21M relationship graph database was able to import successfully using the import tool relatively quickly (didn't hang at relationship count).

Any thoughts as to what could be going wrong? Thanks in advance!

If it helps to look at my nodes/relationships files, here is a link to them:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw7N-SlJA3ZCei0ycEhoa2YwNUU

Here is the neo4j shell output:

```
C:Users\Username\Documents\Neo4j>neo4jImport -into graphDB1.graphdb --nodes D:\concept.csv --relationships D:\predicate.csv --stacktrace --idtype integer
WARNING! This batch script has been deprecated. Please use the provided PowerShell scripts instead: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/powershell.html
The system cannot find the path specified.
Importing the contents of these files into graphDB1.graphdb:
Nodes:
  D:\concept.csv
Relationships:
      D:\predicate.csv

Available memory:
  Free machine memory: 13.50 GB
  Max heap memory : 12.75 GB

    Nodes
[>:|PR|NOD|*LABEL SCAN---------------------------------|v:6.79 MB/s----------------------------]  1M
Done in 40s 562ms
Prepare node index
[*DETECT:20.37 MB------------------------------------------------------------------------------]  1M
Done in 802ms
Calculate dense nodes
[*>:59.38 MB/s----------------------------------|PREPARE(3)====================================] 20M
Done in 12s 566ms
Relationships
[>:2.01 |PREPARE-----------|P|RELATIONSHI|*v:4.05 MB/s-----------------------------------------] 20M
Done in 6m 3s 655ms
Node --> Relationship
[>:3.19 MB/s--------------------------|L|*v:2.39 MB/s------------------------------------------]  1M
Done in 8s 421ms
Relationship --> Relationship
[*>:6.82 MB/s--------------------------------------|LINK-----------|v:6.82 MB/s----------------] 20M
Done in 1m 36s 849ms
Node counts
[*COUNT:91.55 MB-------------------------------------------------------------------------------]  1M
Done in 3m 35s 21ms
Relationship counts
[*>:8.62 MB/s-----------------------------------------------------------|COUNT-----------------] 20MException in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.stats.StepStats.<init>(StepStats.java:39)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.stats(AbstractStep.java:220)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.StageExecution$1.compare(StageExecution.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.StageExecution$1.compare(StageExecution.java:118)
        at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.StageExecution.stepsOrderedBy(StageExecution.java:117)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.DynamicProcessorAssigner.assignProcessorsToPotentialBottleNeck(DynamicProcessorAssigner.java:94)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.DynamicProcessorAssigner.check(DynamicProcessorAssigner.java:81)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.MultiExecutionMonitor.check(MultiExecutionMonitor.java:106)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.supervise(ExecutionSupervisor.java:65)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisors.superviseExecution(ExecutionSupervisors.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.executeStages(ParallelBatchImporter.java:224)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:185)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:363)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:279)
```

UPDATE 1:

Here is the thread dump at the moment(s) that the import hangs at relationship counts:

```
2016-02-17 08:28:12
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode):

"MuninnPageCache[1]-FlushTask" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000026855800 nid=0xfe0 waiting on condition [0x00000000288fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000004c0189810> (a org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.continuouslyFlushPages(MuninnPageCache.java:909)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.FlushTask.run(FlushTask.java:36)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.BackgroundTask.run(BackgroundTask.java:45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"MuninnPageCache[1]-EvictionTask" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000026904000 nid=0x3bd4 runnable [0x00000000287fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000004c0189810> (a org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.parkEvictor(MuninnPageCache.java:697)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.parkUntilEvictionRequired(MuninnPageCache.java:751)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.continuouslySweepPages(MuninnPageCache.java:732)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.EvictionTask.run(EvictionTask.java:39)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.BackgroundTask.run(BackgroundTask.java:45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000024ee8000 nid=0x301c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000024ee6000 nid=0x3060 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000024ee2800 nid=0x2198 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000024ee2000 nid=0x1ae4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000024ee1000 nid=0x135c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x0000000024ed9000 nid=0x3480 in Object.wait() [0x00000000278ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000004c000d4b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000004c000d4b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000024ed8000 nid=0x1ae8 in Object.wait() [0x00000000277ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000004c000d300> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000004c000d300> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023c2800 nid=0x2e7c waiting on condition [0x00000000023bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.FileUtils.waitAndThenTriggerGC(FileUtils.java:253)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.FileUtils.deleteFile(FileUtils.java:110)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.deleteFile(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:127)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.FileOperation$3.perform(FileOperation.java:93)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreFile.fileOperation(StoreFile.java:267)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:389)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:279)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000024ed1800 nid=0x3058 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023d7000 nid=0x313c runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023d9000 nid=0x3144 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023da800 nid=0x974 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023dc000 nid=0x3a3c runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023de800 nid=0x3684 runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023e1000 nid=0x35b8 runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023e4000 nid=0x3950 runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023e5800 nid=0x318c runnable

"GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023e8800 nid=0x30b8 runnable

"GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000023e9800 nid=0x32dc runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000024eed800 nid=0x3710 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 377

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 2071552K, used 0K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 2043904K, 0% used [0x0000000780000000,0x0000000780000000,0x00000007fcc00000)
  from space 27648K, 0% used [0x00000007fe500000,0x00000007fe500000,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 25600K, 0% used [0x00000007fcc00000,0x00000007fcc00000,0x00000007fe500000)
 ParOldGen       total 11534336K, used 10982258K [0x00000004c0000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 11534336K, 95% used [0x00000004c0000000,0x000000075e4dcb50,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 13521K [0x00000004bae00000, 0x00000004bc300000, 0x00000004c0000000)
  object space 21504K, 62% used [0x00000004bae00000,0x00000004bbb34588,0x00000004bc300000)

2016-02-17 08:28:20
```

Answer (score 0):

That is very strange on such a small dataset. How many unique relationships and labels do you expect there to be in this dataset? Also can you provide a thread dump some way into that pause when it happens?

EDIT: problem was that a column containing property values was used as `LABEL`. This produced an enormous amount of labels by mistake and the counting doesn't scale with that.

Comment: All of the nodes are unique and I updated the MySQL table that is exported to CSV just now so the (START_ID, TYPE, END_ID) relationship triplets in the data file should be unique, as well. This did cause the relationships csv to be reduced from ~21M to ~20M rows so I re-ran the import. Unfortunately, it is still hanging at Relationship count. Also, I added the thread dump to the question.

Comment: Also, not sure it's helpful but I added a link to the node and relationship csv files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The thread dump seems to be from after the exception happened, which isn't really useful as it won't tell where it was before the exception happened. Make sure you grab one before the exception happens.

Comment: Oh, wait you're using a the `PREFERRED_NAME1:LABEL` columns as labels, which means that most nodes will have different labels, like every new node will have it's new unique label. That's what causing the explosion in the counting stage. You're expected to have a few (tens,hundreds or so) labels/relationship types in a database.

Comment: Ahh, that was the problem. I dropped that column and the import worked. Thanks! If you want to edit your answer now, I'll go ahead and accept it.